# htaccess rule to avoid duplicates ending with index.php

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have page duplicates with ending /index.php

Examples:

domain.com/

domain.com/index.php - duplicated

---

domain.com/about

domain.com/about/index.php - duplicated

---

domain.com/blog/article

domain.com/blog/article/index.php - duplicated

---

Site is based on WordPress and currently there is such rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

What rule should I add to make all pages ending with index.php -> response with 404?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What rule should I add to make all pages ending with index.php -> response with 404?

You can use this rule just below `RewriteBase` line:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```